# Render data for autocompletion from a MongoDB database

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-3.x, mongodb, autocomplete

I am trying to generate an autocompletion in an HTML field. I want to change the source of the data from hardcoded to myMongoDB database. I was able to render the data from an hardcoded array with:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var perfumes = ["dior", "pacco", "moschino"];

  $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: perfumes,
    minLength: 0
  }).focus(function() {
    /* Muestra todas las opciones al enfocar el input */
    $(this).autocomplete('search', $(this).val())
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="recommendations">
  <!-- <div class="login-page"> -->
  <div class="form">
    <form class="form" action="{% url 'similar_results' %}" method="get" autocomplete="off">
      <input id="autocomplete" type="text" placeholder="Perfume name...">
      <input id="perfumename" type="submit" value="Find Similar Perfumes" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- jQuery-UI CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" />
  <!-- jQuery-Min JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- jQuery-UI JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</div>
```

But when trying to adapt it to data I have from a query to an Index of a MongoDB database, it's not as simple. Indeed, this:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: async function(request, response) {
            let data = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/similar/similar_results/?query=${request.term}`)
                .then(results => results.json())
                .then(results => results.map(result => {
                    return { label: result.name, value: result.name, id: result._id };
                }));
            response(data);
        }
    });
  });
```

Doesn't render anything. Even if `http://localhost:8000/similar/similar_results/?query=${request.term}` returns the expected documents.

I also tried to do something close to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqvhuatr/1/), which works well

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  const datos = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/similar/similar_results/?query=${request.term}`);
  const filtrar = (w) => {
    return datos

  }
  // handle click and add class
  $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: async function(request, response) {
        let data = filtrar().map(result => {
                return { label: result.name, value: result.name, id: result._id };
            });
        response(data);
    },
    minLength:2,
    select: function(event, ui){
      console.log(ui.item);
    }
  });
})
```

But my attempt doesn't.

## Update

```
Django version 3.1.1, using settings 'scentmate.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
JE SUIS PASSE PAR LA # This shows we went through the Django code which query the database
JE SUIS PASSE PAR LA # This shows we went through the Django code which query the database
[27/Mar/2021 19:01:20] "GET /similar/similar_results/?query=at HTTP/1.1" 200 11389
[27/Mar/2021 19:01:21] "GET /similar/similar_results/?query=atel HTTP/1.1" 200 11389
```

Here is the code that query the database:

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Perfume
    template_name = 'todo/search_similar_results.html'

    def get_queryset(self):  # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        print("JE SUIS PASSE PAR LA")
        # object_list = list(collection.find({"q0.Results.0.Name": {"$regex": str(query), "$options": "i"}}))
        object_list = list(collection.aggregate([
                {
                    '$search': {
                        'index': 'default',
                        'compound': {
                            'must': {
                                'text': {
                                    'query': str(query),
                                    'path': 'name',
                                    'fuzzy': {
                                        'maxEdits': 2
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        ))
        # print(object_list[0])
        return object_list
```

Comment: did you check if `data` has any value ?

Comment: @Swati I tried. I am very new to javascript so I did a console.log like at the 9th line of [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=hL8U4Fp1hN) but nothing goes out of that ...

Comment: Can you try like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/fpdckb36/) see if that works . Make sure if the url is right in that fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution @Swati I just tried it. On the one hand as you can see in the update of the output in the console I still have query to [the function in `views.py`](https://github.com/antoinecomp/todowoo/blob/51e4291015c6a700a38a1cb9d1881a58f7cb21ef/todo/views.py#L219) in the django backend. But, on the other end, no autocomplete pops up. I've also added a `console.log("some string");` after the `$ajax` function but nothing shows up. I'm really a noob in javascript.

Comment: You are getting that parameter pass with ajax using `..get('q')` this should be `get('query')`

Comment: Yeah, but it seems to work as `object_list` gets all the documents I was looking for

Comment: any error inside browser console ? are you sure nothing shows up ? atleast you should get some error

Comment: No, no error, and nothing shows up

Comment: not even `alert(data)` showing ?

Comment: @Swati Not even alert(data), but alerts before and after the bunch of code related to `autocomplete` are shown.

Comment: please update your code so it would be easy to find out what's wrong :) . I am not sure which code you are talking about ajax or await .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source is pretty clear on the interface for the function as a source:

> **Function**: The third variation, a callback, provides the most flexibility and can be used to connect any data source to Autocomplete, including JSONP. The callback gets two arguments:
>
> - A `request` object, with a single `term` property, which refers to the value currently in the text input. For example, if the user enters `"new yo"` in a city field, the Autocomplete term will equal `"new yo"`.
> - A `response` callback, which expects a single argument: the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on the provided term, and can be in any of the formats described above for simple local data. It's important when providing a custom source callback to handle errors during the request. You must always call the `response` callback even if you encounter an error. This ensures that the widget always has the correct state.

You return call the response callback with an array of objects `{ label: result.name, value: result.name, id: result._id };` which doesn't match the documented format. Return a plain string in your map's lambda instead:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            fetch(`http://localhost:8000/similar/similar_results/?query=${request.term}`)
                .then(results => results.json())
                .then(results => results.map(result => result.name))
                .then(response);
        }
    });
  });
```

As a side note, try to avoid mixing promises with async/await syntax. Pick the one you prefer and keep it consistent. It will make the code a bit easier to maintain and may help you to prevent unexpected behaviour.